# using conditional in CASE does not evaluate expressions properly ? neo4j

Tags: string, neo4j, trim

I would like to trim strings server side.

Consider this: a property is string, and I want to trim it if longer than, say, 10 chars.
Consider this query:

```
Match (r)
with r, case r.what
    when size(r.what) > 10 then substring(r.what, 0, 10)
    else r.what end as w
return {what : w, len : size(w)} as props
```

I expect `size(r.what) > 10` evaluate to true and `substring(r.what, 0, 10)` assigned to variable `w`,  `w` is always equal to the original string '`r.what`', no matter of length.
`len` is reported correctly.

What am I doing wrong?
Im using neo4j 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `r.what` after the `CASE`. Your query should look like this:

```
MATCH (r)
WITH r,
     CASE
       WHEN size(r.what) > 10 THEN substring(r.what, 0, 10)
       else r.what
     END AS w
RETURN {what : w, len : size(w)} AS props
```

When you add an expression after the `CASE` (in your problem, the `r.what`), its value will be compared to whatever you put on each `WHEN`.

Sources:

- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#syntax-simple-case
- https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#syntax-generic-case

Comment: ohh! thank you. So basically I was comparing "r.what" == "size(...)" that evaluates to false, therefore else.

Comment: Exactly. Glad to be of help!